# how doI add html and css directly to my flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is there anyway to add HTML, JS to my flutter web project and interact with it other than using   IFrameElement() in platfromviewRegistry ?

Comment: I have been using IFrameElement